# Como criar arquivo em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#, arquivo

Na minha aplicação, preciso converter uma string que contém **XML** para **RTF**. A forma que encontrei de realizar tal tarefa é com o seguinte código abaixo, que utiliza arquivos em vez de strings. Então eu precisaria criar durante *runtime* um arquivo para formato: **XLM**, **XSLT**, **RTF**. Como posso fazer isso?

```
string string_xlm = "conteúdo qualquer";
string string_xslt = "conteúdo qualquer";

//criar arquivo doc_xml com conteúdo da string_xlm
//criar arquivo doc_xslt com conteúdo da string_xslt
//criar arquivo doc_rtf vazio

/*----------------------------------------------------*/
XslCompiledTransform xml2rtf = new XslCompiledTransform();
xml2rtf.Load(doc_xslt);
xml2rtf.Transform(doc_xml, doc_rtf);
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

string string_rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(doc_rtf);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se isso vai resolver seu problema, mas, focando apenas na escrita do arquivo:

**Método 1:**

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\arquivo.extensao", "conteudo", Encoding.Default);
```

**Método 2:**

```
string rtf = "(conteúdo rtf)";

using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\doc_rtf.rtf",false,Encoding.Default))
{
    tw.Write(rtf);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Para um arquivo Xml, você ainda pode usar o `XmlDocument`, mas também funciona da forma acima.